# passing value from php to jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I need some help, I want to know how can I pass a value, from a PHP variable to jquery script?
What I'm doing is openning a modal window, from a list of elements created from a mysql browse, so I need to pass trhough the anchor a variable value. 
Here is my code :

```
<?php
$query_tours = "Select * from tours where feautured  = 'Y' " ;
$result_tours = mysql_query($query_tours);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_tours )) { 
           $tourID    = $row['recid'];
    $tit_esp   = $row['tit_esp'];
    $adrate    = $row['ad_rate'];
    $chrate    = $row['ch_rate'];
    echo '<div style="border:1px solid #EEE;font-size:12px">';
        print "$tit_esp <br>"; 
        print "Adultos : $adrate | Ni&ntilde;os : $chrate   ";
        print "<a href='#?tourid=$tourID' class='myTour_$tourID' >ver       detalles</a>";
       print "</div>";
     }
```

?>

here is jquery script:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

    var adult = $( "#adult" ),
        child = $( "#chl" ),
        fecha = $("#datepicker"),




        allFields = $( [] ).add( adult ).add( child ).add( fecha ),
        tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
        tips
            .text( t )
            .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
        setTimeout(function() {
            tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
        }, 500 );
    }


    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {

        if ( o.val()> max || o.val()< min ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "El numero de " + n + " debes ser entre " +
                min + " y " + max + "." );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    function checkFecha() {
        var dfecha = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;

        if(dfecha == ""){  
            //dfecha.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( "Fecha Incorrecta");
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }


    }   

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
        if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
            o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        height: 300,
        width: 410,
        modal: true,
        show : {
            transitionIn: 'blind',
            transitionOut: 'explode',
        },
        open: function(event, ui) {
           $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker('enable'); 

           alert(regis)

            $.ajax({   
                url: 'tour_cont.php',
                data: "regis=" + regis + "",
                dataType: 'json',   
                success: function(data){
                     var titulo = data[1];   
                     var user  = data[3];    
                     var comenta = data[4];  
                     $( "#dialog-form" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td width='21%'>" + titulo + "</td>" +  "</tr>" ); 

                     }
            });

        },

        buttons: {
            "Agregar al Carrito": function() {
                var bValid = true;

                bValid = bValid && checkFecha( datepicker );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( adult, "adultos", 1, 10 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( child, "niños", 0, 10 );

                if ( bValid ) {

                    $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + adult.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + child.val() + "</td>" + 
                        "<td>" + fecha.val() + "</td>" + 

                    "</tr>" ); 
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
            $('#datepicker').datepicker('disable');
        }
    });

    $('a[class^=myTour]')
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });




    $( "#create-chichen" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });


});
</script>
```

Hope somebody understad me, thank you in advanced !!!

Comment: You dont need to post all your codes, only post that is relevant to your question.

Answer (score 3):

you can pass a php value into javascript like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myJSval = <?php echo $phpVal; ?>;
</script>
```